# Install shield SQL Connection Provider

Tags: sql-server, installshield

Installshield executes SQL scripts file, Installshiled use OLEDB provider.
I want installshield to use SQLCLIENT provider.

due to OLEDB I get error.

> 1: ADO Error: Number: -2147467259 Description:
>   [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security
>   error. Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server SQL State:
>   08001 Native Error: 18  MSI (s) (AC!D0) [16:30:38:084]: Product: XXX
>   -- Error 27502.Could not connect to Microsoft SQL Server ''. [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen (SECDoClientHandshake()).]SSL Security
>   error. (18)

I searched solution for this error and some user used SQL Client instead of OLEBD it worked.
How to force installshield to use SQLCLIENT provider?

Comment: It's been many years since I used InstallShield but I used to perform database installation tasks using a .NET custom action, which used SqlClient. The reference to ADO in the error suggests the out-of-the-box provider is unmanaged.

Comment: Thank you. 
I have switched to .net managed assembly custom action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Direct Editor --> ISSQLDBMetaData --> Change AdoDriverName to SQLNCLI11 in install shield project for youe installer.

Comment: thank you, looks like It should work. 
I had already resolved using managed assembly.
In install-shield direct editor, there i could not find option to put always encrypted flags and trust server certificate options.
Managed assembly give more flexibility in this case.

Comment: For those who haven't worked much with InstallShield and have no idea where to find this mysterious Direct Editor and what it is. Direct Editor is included in InstallShield. Scroll down in the left menu to Additional Tools if you're using InstallShield 2022 (it may also be the case in earlier versions). Under Additional Tools, you will see Dependency Scanners, MSI Debugger, and Direct Editor. Click on Direct Editor, and it will open.

Comment: @dilipkumarkatre I am new to install shield and I am using v 2020 R3. Can you tell me where I can find options to set this encrypted flags and trust server certificate? Thanks

Comment: I had achieve Secured SQL Connection using .net dll

Comment: Can you share a reference on how you did it? Thanks